# Is Synfusion with npm Packages are Paid Version or Free

Tags: npm, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion

Is Synfusion with npm Packages are Paid Version or Free, if i installed by npm Package in Angular application to use grid **@syncfusion/ej2-angular-grids**

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion (SF) libraries are not free. However, you can pledge to a community license, which allows you to use SF libraries under certain conditions:

- $1M in U.S. revenue
- fewer than five developers

Here is a [link](https://www.syncfusion.com/sales/licensing) for a reference.